# How to print file contents with filename before each line?

Tags: python, perl, bash, scripting, sed

I have several files, say, a,b,c, I would like to something like

```
 > cat a b c
```

but with "a,"  in the beginning lines of a. "b," in the beginning of the lines of b and "c," in the beginning of the lines of c.
I can do this using python:

```
#!/bin/env python

files = 'a b c'

all_lines = []
for f in files.split():
  lines = open(f, 'r').readlines()
  for line in lines:
    all_lines.append(f + ',' + line.strip())

fout = open('out.csv', 'w')
fout.write('\n'.join(all_lines))
fout.close()
```

but I would prefer to do it in the command line, combining some simple commands with the pipe | operator.

Is there a easy way of accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perl -pe 'print "$ARGV,"' a b c
```

will do it.

Answer (score 5):

`grep(1)` and `sed(1)`can do this for you: `grep -H '' <files> | sed 's/:/,/'`:

```
$ cat a ; cat b ; cat c
hello


world
from space
$ grep -H '' * | sed 's/:/,/'
a,hello
b,
b,
b,world
c,from space
```

Comment: It is clever, but you might want to add a `-H` option to `grep`, in case there's only one file.

Comment: More portable than `grep -H`: `grep '' /dev/null a b c`

Comment: @Gilles, very good advice, thanks. It's harder to integrate into a simple example though, so here's hoping flagging the comment as useful brings it to people's attention well enough. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `awk(1)` program :)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=","; } {print FILENAME , $0;}' *
a,hello
b,
b,
b,world
c,from space
d,,flubber
```

Comment: why don't you set OFS to comma?